# Keystone js audio video support and connection with rethink db?

Tags: node.js, express, rethinkdb, keystonejs, rethinkdb-javascript

I am new to keystone js, I am looking to answer these questions:

1. Can we add/view video/audio in gallery view ?
2. Can we connect keystone js with Rethink db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can add audio/video in gallery view but default database for keystone js is mongoDB 
here is the detailed DB setup for keystone js
http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/